# C++ defining const in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, constants

I am getting error on line 30 (const Date date2 = new Date(31, 12, 2012);)

Error message is : 
conversion from ‘Date*’ to non-scalar type ‘const Date’ requested

Below is my source code:

```
class Date
{
private :
    int day ;
    int month ;
    int year ;
public :
    Date(){
        day = 1;
        month = 1;
        year = 2000;
    }
    Date(int d, int m, int y) : day(d), month(m), year(y){
    }
    int getDay () const { return day ;}
    int getMonth () const { return month ;}
    int getYear () const { return year ;}
};

int main ()
{
    const Date date ;
    const Date date2 = new Date(31, 12, 2012);

    cout <<"The month is "<< date.getMonth()<< endl ;
    cout << " The month is "<<date2.getMonth()<< endl ;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `const Date date2 = new Date(31, 12, 2012);` works in Java but not c++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
const Date date2(31, 12, 2012);
```

In your code, `const Date date2` is a `Date` whereas `new Date(31, 12, 2012);` returns a pointer to a `Date` (which leaks, incidentally).

Answer (score 1):

Well, using `new` returns a pointer that you try to assign to a non-pointer const variable.

Answer (score 1):

*Problem is in your code:*

**1.const Date date2 = new Date(31, 12, 2012);**

Here you are dynamically allocating memory for object `Date`.Operator `new` will return pointer so that you need to take in to the pointer type of object example

`const Date *date2 = new Date(31, 12, 2012);`

**2.cout << " The month is " << date2.getMonth()<< endl ;**

If you modify the code as per point 1 then above line has to be changed as 
So if `date2` is pointer then you need to call function as :

`cout <<"The month is"<<date2->getMonth()<<endl ;`

**3.If you want to use your code then you just remove `new` from below line:**

```
const Date date2 = Date(31, 12, 2012);
```

**You need to modify your code as :**

```
int main ()
{
    const Date date ;
    const Date *date2 = new Date(31, 12, 2012);
    cout << " The month is " << date.getMonth() << endl ;
    cout << " The month is " << date2->getMonth() << endl ;
    return 0;
}
```

**or**

```
int main ()
{
    const Date date ;
    const Date date2 = Date(31, 12, 2012);
    cout << " The month is " << date.getMonth() << endl ;
    cout << " The month is " << date2.getMonth() << endl ;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`operator new` returns a pointer, if you really need a pointer, you should use

```
const Date* date2 = new Date(31,12,2012);
```

instead.
And don't forget to `delete date2`.

Or you can do either:

```
const Date date2(31,12,2012);
```

or

```
const Date date2 = Date(31,12,2012);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const Date date2 = new Date(31, 12, 2012);
```

This line results in an error because `date2` has the type `Date` but the result of the right-hand side has the type `Date*`.  This is because of the way `new` works.

Per Paragraph 5.3.4/2 of the C++11 Standard:

> Entities created by a new-expression have dynamic storage duration (3.7.4). [ -- ] If the entity is a non-array object, the new-expression returns a pointer to the object created. If it is an array, the new-expression returns a pointer to the initial element of the array.

So now we know that `new` allocates memory for its operand on the heap and returns a stack-allocated pointer to it. You might of had a misconception that `new` creates an object (like in Java, JavaScript or C#) but this is not the case in C++. For the above line to work you would have to make `date2` a pointer:

```
const Date *date2 = new Date(31, 12, 2012);
```

However, the normal way of creating an object is to simply do the following (in your case):

```
const Date date2(31, 12, 2012);
```